# Is there a browser-compatibility database with support for multiple feature search?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I'm looking/hoping for a tool similar to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com) that supports searching for multiple features in one go.

Instead of searching for a single feature (like "border-radius"), I'd like to input all the HTML/CSS/JS APIs/etc that a given site uses, and be presented with a single table of browser support levels for *all* the features, in aggregate.

Example search: *border-radius, FileAPI, canvas, video, audio*

The idea is that you could provide a list of all the features of a given site and get a pretty accurate list of which browsers will support every bit of that site's functionality.  It would answer the question of "Is browser X compatible with my site?", whereas caniuse answers the question "Is browser X compatible with feature Y?"

Does something like this exist?

Comment: What about http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus/ It's not exactly what you requested but more convenient than searching for one thing at a time.

Comment: @davidkennedy85: you should post this as an answer on the question, that's pretty useful.

Comment: @calvinf since it wasn't the answer to the question the OP was asking I wasn't sure...

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of.

caniuse has a link at the top of the page for Suggestions.  You should suggest this.

It may be difficult to aggregate support information for multiple features particularly in cases where features have limited browser support, are available only by vendor-prefixes, or have known issues in particular cases.

Comment: I suggested it right after posting this question. :)  The actual processing of the results wouldn't be too hard: search for each feature independently, then overlay the tables, and for each cell, display the support level for the least-supported browser.  I agree though that some information will be lost, but this would be answering a different question than the standard search.

Answer (score 0):

What about [this site](http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus)? It's not exactly what you requested but more convenient than searching for one thing at a time.

Comment: looks like that page no longer exists